# String functions in MediaWiki template?

Tags: templates, string, wiki, mediawiki

One of the more interesting "programming languages" I've been stuck with lately is MediaWiki templates.  You can do a surprising amount of stuff with the limited syntax they give you, but recently I've run into a problem that stumps me: using string functions on template arguments.  What I'd like to do (somewhat simplified) is:

```
{{myTemp|a=1,2,3,4}}
```

then write a template that can do some sort of magic like

```
You told me _a_ starts with {{#split:{{{a}}}, ",", 0}}
```

At present, I can do this with embedded javascript, capturing regexp matching, and document.write, but a) it's huge, b) it's hacky, and c) it will break horribly if anybody turns off javascript.  (Note that "split" is merely an example; concatenate, capturing-regexp matching, etc., would be even better)

I realize the *right* solution is to have the caller invoke the template with separate arguments, but for various reasons that would be hard in my particular case.  If it's simply not possible, I guess that's the answer, but if there *is* some way to have templates do string-manipulation on the back end, that'd be great.

Comment: would you like to accept one of the answers and do some up-voting?

Comment: Both good answers, but I picked relet specifically because I had been looking for regexp support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concatenate is easy. To assign `x = y concat z`

```
{{#vardefine:x|{{{y}}}{{{z}}}}}
```

And, to add to Mark's answer, there are also [RegexParserFunctions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:RegexParserFunctions)

Ceterum censeo: MediaWiki will never be not hacky.

Comment: Which extension do I need for #vardef? Doesn't seem to work on My MediaWiki installation.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The template is called #vardefine.

Comment: Hmmm... still doesn't work... See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:X5
Is this available only in a specific MediaWiki version? Or in an extension?

Comment: Oh, I found it: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Variables
Not installed on Wikipedia though. :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with extensions, e.g. [StringFunctions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StringFunctions). But see also [ParserFunctions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) and [ParserFunctions/Extended](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions/Extended). (You'll find a lot more examples in the [Category:Parser function extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Parser_function_extensions).)

A great overview [Help:Extension:ParserFunctions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions).